# Does the length of a frame influence the likelihood of a collision?

Tags: layer2, layer1

Considering two separate analog signals on the same frequency transmitting digital data that represents a frame, from my understanding if any portion of the two signals overlap, this is a collision.

Then would a longer frame, due to it occupying more space, increase the probability of a collision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest terms, if the systems don't have any carrier sense mechanisms, then yes.  Longer transmit times increase the probability.

But in Ethernet, with CSMA/CD, stations check whether the medium is free before attempting to transmit.  So a station will not transmit if the media is occupied.  The probability of a collision is a function of the propagation delay of the medium.  That's independent of the frame length.